# React-Leaflet LayersControl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Is there possible to add a select box like react-select at LayersControl from React-Leaflet? I just got LayersControl.BaseLayer or LayersControl.Overlay options but they are check boxes.

LayersControl TopRight menu:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div>
    <Map
      zoom={this.state.zoom}
      maxZoom={20}
      bounds={this.getBounds()}
    >
      <TileLayer
        minZoom={0}
        maxZoom={22}
        maxNativeZoom={18}
        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <LayersControl position="topright">
        <LayersControl.BaseLayer name="Preto e Branco">
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://tiles.wmflabs.org/bw-mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
        </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
        <LayersControl.BaseLayer name="Estradas">
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
        </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
        {this.addMarkers()}
      </LayersControl>
      <GeoJSON data={jsonData} style={this.geoJsonStyle()} />
    </Map>
  </div>
```

I could not find anything at [React-Leaflet Documentation](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components.html#controls).

Thanks to advance!

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Please clarify as it is not clear as the question is currently written

Comment: Edited. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes much better now. So you want to have an input inside Layer.Control?

Comment: I already got the menu on top right with those check boxes options. I want to change those options into options of a select box.

Comment: Ok, so you to place 01,02,03,04 inside a drop down list?

Comment: Yes. Those options inside a drop down list inside that menu. That menu is created by LayersControl component.

Comment: As a starting point take a look [here](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#layer-switching-controls) to see some plugins which extend L.control's appearance. I am not sure there is a plugin with a drop-down list therefore most likely you will have to write your own custom plugin to achieve that.